# Is it possible to send googleAPIClient connect callback to another class?

Tags: android, callback

Is it possible to send callback to another class?

I have app class as follow:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    public MyApp(){
        // bla... and initialize google client here...
        this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this.getApplicationContext())
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, this.GSO()).build();
    }
}
```

and I have main class as follow:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyApp app;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        app = (MyApp) this.getApplication();
    }

    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        GoogleApiClientUtility googleApiClientUtility = new GoogleApiClientUtility(app, new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks(){
            @Override
            public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                // i want app.mGoogleApiClient ConnectionCallbacks listen to this code
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                // i want app.mGoogleApiClient ConnectionCallbacks listen to this code
            }
        });
        googleApiClientUtility.connect();
    }
}
```

and with GoogleApiClientUtility class as below:

```
public class GoogleApiClientUtility {

    private MyApp mApp;

    public GoogleApiClientUtility(MyApp app, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks callbacks){
        mApp = app;
    }

    public final void connect() {
        /* how to do this below???
         * mApp.getGoogleApiClient().registerConnectionCallbacks(????) 
         * so it can send to onConnect listener in MyActivity Class above
         */
        mApp.getGoogleApiClient().connect();
    }
}
```

is there a way for me to set the call back function to the 'caller class'?

Thank you,

Comment: yes it is posible

Comment: Create a utility class for GoogleApiClient and send callback to multiple classes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with clue from @Abdul Waheed (+1),

I fix it as below:
create utility class:

```
class GoogleApiClientUtility {

    private GoogleApiClient mClient;
    private GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mCallbacks;

    GoogleApiClientUtility(GoogleApiClient app, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks callbacks) {
        mClient = app;
        mCallbacks = callbacks;
    }

    final void connect() {
        mClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(mCallbacks);
        mClient.connect();
    }

}
```

and in my Main activity Class:

```
// private MyApp app; <-- declared within main activity class
GoogleApiClientUtility googleApiClientUtility = new GoogleApiClientUtility(
                    app.getGoogleApiClient(),
                    new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                            Log.e("GoogleApiClient: %s", "onConnected");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            Log.e("GoogleApiClient: %s", "onConnectionSuspended");
                        }
                    }
            );
            googleApiClientUtility.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that,

1. Write an interface class.
2. Implement the interface where you want call back
3. Pass that interface reference in the constructor
4. Call interface method via reference you passed (in success or false case accordingly)

Hope you get the idea. Further, I am adding code for your reference which I implemented in one of my projects.

```
   private void startScan() {
    BarcodeReaderUtility barcodeReaderUtility = new BarcodeReaderUtility(mContext, new BarcodeReaderUtility.BarcodeTextProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onReadingSuccessfully(String barcode) {
            etBarcode.setText(barcode);
            etBarcode.setSelection(barcode.length());
        }
    });
    barcodeReaderUtility.getBarCode();
}
```

And below is that class that has interface and the reference that was passed via constructor. Please have a look at that if you found any problem. Do ask
public class BarcodeReaderUtility {

```
private BarcodeTextProvider mBarcodeProvider;
private Context mContext;

public BarcodeReaderUtility(Context context, BarcodeTextProvider barcodeTextProvider) {
    mContext = context;
    mBarcodeProvider = barcodeTextProvider;
}

public final void getBarCode() {
    final MaterialBarcodeScanner materialBarcodeScanner = new MaterialBarcodeScannerBuilder()
            .withActivity((Activity) mContext)
            .withEnableAutoFocus(true)
            .withBleepEnabled(true)
            .withBackfacingCamera()
            .withCenterTracker()
            .withText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.scanning))
            .withResultListener(new MaterialBarcodeScanner.OnResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Barcode barcode) {
                    String barCodeResult  = barcode.rawValue;
                    mBarcodeProvider.onReadingSuccessfully(barCodeResult);
                }
            })
            .build();
    materialBarcodeScanner.startScan();
}

public interface BarcodeTextProvider {
    void onReadingSuccessfully(String barcode);
}
```

}

Comment: the diffrent between your code and mine is: in `public final void getBarCode` materialBarcodeScanner is initialize/defined there, while in my code, `mGoogleApiClient` has been defined in `context` then how to link the listener? - let me try to edit my question for you to see